# Citation Management in Latex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am writing a long manuscript that includes dozens of citations in LaTex. Managing this amount of references is going to be a challenging task. I was wondering if there is any way to manage the citations in LaTex (BibTex) like EndNote in Microsoft Word to avoid adding duplicate citations and having instant access to each one.

Sometimes, specifying only a simple name for each item in the bibliography is confusing as you have to go through your BibTex file to find one that you would like to cite in your text by e.g. \cite{c54} (where 'c54' is the name of the desired citation).

Comment: PS: think of a system for naming your keys. I always use `AuthorYear`, i.e. `\cite{Cesar2018}`. This makes it much easier to remember the keys and prevent duplicates.

Comment: Consider using [JabRef](http://www.jabref.org/).

Comment: Or if you're using a Mac, [BibDesk](https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/). See [Bibliography tools that are compatible with biblatex and biber](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/23942).  Some people also use Mendelay or Zotero.

Answer (score 2):

[JabRef](http://www.jabref.org/)  can rename automatically some-all your keycodes based in reference contents, by default the surname of the first author plus the year (e.g.; `Smith1981`) ensuring unique keys in case of several references of the same first author and year (e.g.:`Smith1981a`, `Smith1981b` ...).

Moreover, in <kbd>Options</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>BibTeX key generator</kbd>  you can change the default key pattern  `[auth][year]` to some other globally or for each type of type of reference, for instance `[year][auth]` for books. The windows is at first is unintuitive since is not clear what others patterns are available, until you discover the little <kbd>(?)</kbd> button that link to the right [help page](http://help.jabref.org/en/BibtexKeyPatterns). 
I never had the need of touch the default `[auth][year]`, though.

Besides this, before of import some references jabRef warns you about possible duplicates.

JabRef, is a Java based program, so it works on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS, so I support also the Werner's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Fran.  JabRef is exactly what I was looking for! Now, I can readily manage my references and have a full control over them in a long document.